# infix to postfix conversion - precedence

Tags: data-structures

which one has highest precedence * or ^?

According to PEMDAS rule  ^ is highest precedance

```
infix: a*b^c
Output: abc^*
```

But in some websites the answer is ab*c^. Which one is right?

Comment: You can apply any precedence rule you want. My suggestion would be to implement the PEDMAS rules. Can you provide a link to the website that shows `ab*c^`?

Comment: Thanks
https://raj457036.github.io/Simple-Tools/prefixAndPostfixConvertor.html

Comment: That converter is using a different precedence rule in which `*` is higher precedence than `^`. This one, http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/prefix-postfix-infix-online-converter, appears to use PEDMAS.

Comment: AFAIK `^` is a slightly informal (albeit common) syntax, so there may not be a strictly correct answer regarding its meaning. You could perhaps argue either interpretation uses PEDMAS, because it comes down to what the `^` syntax actually means, not whether you should do exponents before multiplication. And this is still assuming we're talking about `^` meaning exponent - in some programming languages it means XOR, and has lower precedence  than `*`.

Comment: Thanks then both answers are correct. It depends upon how we are considering an operator and precedence rule.

Comment: The link you provided does actually treat `^` as XOR, not exponentiation - click on Evaluate and evaluate `5 2 ^`, which will give `7` and not `25`.